# Not working tacacs while disabling PasswordAuthentication and ChallengeResponseAuthentication on sshd_config

Tags: sshd, pam

I would like to authenticate via SSH key(id_rsa) for root user. For that I have disabled **PasswordAuthentication** and **ChallengeResponseAuthentication** on sshd_config. So that I'm not getting password promt for tacacs.

1. Do we have any parameter to configure using key based auth or while enabling tacacs it should ask password.
2. I want to disable local users do not authenticate while tacacs enabled.

Could you please suggest on that ?

Thanks,
Vasanth

Comment: Tacacs is a linux utility to handle user level auth in linux. its working as server and client model.

Comment: Point 1: The parameter to enable or disable key-based authentication in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is `PubkeyAuthentication`. There are other parameters that configure it, such as `AuthorizedKeysFile`. I don't think I understand the second part of point 1, though, and you may want to elaborate what you mean in point 2 as well. What is a local user?

Comment: @berndbausch I dont want use root and other users while enabing tacacs. Only tacacs users only can able to login.

Point 1: Public key doesn't have for tacacs. So problem is key is not available may somewhere if key is available please let me know. I'm sure /home/tacacsuser/ doesn't have key in that directory.

Comment: I can't comment on tacacs, as I don't know the tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another similar way. We can restrict through sshd_config.

```
#TACACS user
match user vasanth      
PasswordAuthentication yes
#Other user/root user
match all
PasswordAuthentication no
```

This would work for me.